# how to connect to oracle database using node js javascript without using Visual Studio as pre-requisite

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, oracle, protractor

I want to **fetch data from oracle database** using **node js,javascript** and **protractor**. I tried with node oracledb package which needs visual studio as prerequisite,hence can not install.

I am facing **error: node gyp rebuild** while installing npm package oracledb,db-tool,jdbc etc.

I tried with nashorn engine hovewer it doesn't worked.

Kindly suggest solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a member of the community that maintains pre-compiled binaries. You could use these if you trust the person.

https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/18

Comment: Hi, I tried to install oracledb using the above link but I got following error npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\pankaj\\AppData\
\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "https://github.com
/bchr02/node-oracledb#prebuild_support" "--toolset=oci12.1-msvs2015"
npm ERR! node v6.7.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.2
npm ERR! code ENOGIT

npm ERR! not found: git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.